# How to insert single quotes with redactor.js?

Tags: json, redactor

I'm building a little custom plugin with redactor 8.2.2 to customize links.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve :

```
var insertText = "<a href='#target' data-rel='{\"key\":\"value\"}'>text</a>";

/* later in the code... */
this.execCommand('insertHtml', insertText);
```

I end up with this code in the editor :

```
<a href="#target" data-rel="{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}">text</a>
```

which is finally saved with double quotes in the database, leading to further troubles:

```
<a href="#target" data-rel="{"key";"value"}">text</a>
```

Is there a way to force single quotes?

I also tried to use `insertHtmlAdvanced`, but no link is inserted.

EDIT_***_***

It seems that the problem is not the way `insertText` is formated. Whatever the format is, double quotes are added if the data-rel attribute presents its value between single quotes.
Therefore, the solution might be to find a workaround for the `insertHtml` command, or to post-process the inserted code.

EDIT_***_*_**

According to Imperavi support, JSON should not be used with data-*. I finally found a workaround by deleting any quotes in the JSON string, and adding them later before parsing the data-rel value. However, I guess this is not the most efficient and nicest solution....

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
this.execCommand('insertHtml', insertText.replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
```

Comment: I get this result, which does not work either: `<a href="\'#target\'" data-rel="\'{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}\'">text</a>`